# I'm looking for a way to take the hard coded "Character" data in my Angular app and load it from a separate json file

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a way to take the hard coded "Character" data in my Angular app and load it from a separate json file.

I have a controller for the ($http) thats worked in other apps, I'm just not sure how to strip, pull and access these character names and properties from a JSON file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
     <body>
        <div class="container">



        <div ng-app="polarisApp">
<h1>The Other Guys</h1>
<h3>Custom Events in Nested Controllers</h3>
<div ng-controller="Characters">
    <div class="lList"> <span ng-repeat="name in names" ng-click="changeName()">{{name}}</span>

    </div>
    <div class="cInfo">
        <div ng-controller="Character">
            <label>Name:</label>{{currentName}}
            <br>
            <label>Job:</label>{{currentInfo.job}}
            <br>
            <label>Weapon:</label>{{currentInfo.weapon}}
            <br> <span ng-click="deleteChar()">Delete</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script>

        angular.module('polarisApp', [])
    .controller('Characters', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['Alan', 'Terry', 'Gene', 'Sheila', 'Danson', 'Highsmith', 'Bob'];
    $scope.currentName = $scope.names[0];
    $scope.changeName = function () {
        $scope.currentName = this.name;
        $scope.$broadcast('CharacterChanged', this.name);
    };
    $scope.$on('CharacterDeleted', function (event, removeName) {
        var i = $scope.names.indexOf(removeName);
        $scope.names.splice(i, 1);
        $scope.currentName = $scope.names[0];
        $scope.$broadcast('CharacterChanged', $scope.currentName);

    });
})
    .controller('Character', function ($scope) {
    $scope.info = {
        'Alan': {
            weapon: 'Calculator',
            job: 'Police Officer'
        },
            'Terry': {
            weapon: 'Gun',
            job: 'Police Officer'
        },
            'Gene': {
            weapon: 'None',
            job: 'Police Captain'
        },
            'Sheila': {
            weapon: 'None',
            job: 'M D'
        },
            'Danson': {
            weapon: 'Gun',
            job: 'Police Detective'
        },
            'Highsmith': {
            weapon: 'Gun',
            job: 'Police Detective'
        },
            'Bob': {
            weapon: 'None',
            job: 'Police Accountant'
        }      
    };
    $scope.currentInfo = $scope.info['Alan'];
    $scope.$on('CharacterChanged', function (event, newCharacter) {
        $scope.currentInfo = $scope.info[newCharacter];
    });
    $scope.deleteChar = function () {
        delete $scope.info[$scope.currentName];
        $scope.$emit('CharacterDeleted', $scope.currentName);
    };
});
    </script>
    </body>
```

This is the ($http) controller I wrote.

```
   angular.module('polarisApp')
   .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('character.json')
   .success(function(data) { 
     $scope.characterStatus = data.caracterStatus; 


   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var info = null;
$http.get('character.json').success(function(data) {
    info = data;
});
```

The response from the `$http.get`  request will be the object contained in content.json file. If you need to access Alan's job, you can use  `info.Alan.job` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this controller:

> App.controller('CharacterCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
>   $http.get('characters.json')
>          .then(function(res){
>             $scope.characters = res.data;
>           }); });

Thank you very much for your feedback. I haven't seen that variable you used in any similar controllers. I think I should look into it--Might be missing out on a better way to $http. Thanks.